# CocoaLibSpotify: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context

Tags: objective-c, cocoalibspotify-2.0

when I download the CocoaLibSpotify sample projects and start them in the ios simulator everything works fine.

When I open them on my iPhone 5 (iOS 7.0) I get following error message, when I try to paste my Facebook password (via long-press). Also the paste-tooltip is not displayed.

> Nov  3 10:03:32 Alex-iPhone Empty CocoaLibSpotify Project[2971] : CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

I did not change anything in the settings or code of the sample project, deleted all Spotify apps I built and closed the Spotify app.